# Inheritance bug

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, virtual-functions

I'm trying to code a simple "calculate shape areas" code to practice inheritance and virtual functions but I'm getting a bug (last line) when I try to initialize Circle with an int; "Circle(int p) is inaccessible" and I can't seem to figure out why considering the methods are all public.

```
class Shape
{
    protected:
    int parameter;

    public:
    Shape()
    {
        this->parameter = 0;
    }
    virtual void area() = 0;
};

class Circle: public Shape
{
    Circle(int p)
    {
        this->parameter = p;
    }
    void area()
    {
        cout << "Shape name: Circle\n"
             << "Parameter type: Radius\n"
             << "Area: " << M_PI * pow(parameter, 2) << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Shape* shape_ptr[5];
    for(int i =0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        if(rand()%3 == 0)
            shape_ptr[i] = new Circle(rand()%10 +1);
    }
}
```

Comment: `class Cicrle` does not have "all public" methods. Remember `class` implies private members by default.

Comment: this has nothing to do with the inheritance. Default access for members in a class defined with `class` is `private`

Comment: The default access in a `class` is `private`. If you want the functions to be public you need to add that as you did in `Shape`.

Comment: Access level of a method is NOT inherited.